# Picker setting selectedItem on second click [Xamarin]

Tags: c#, xamarin, picker

I have a picker getting values from an Enum. On select it should display value 'title' but then bind the actual integer value to an integer variable. I have made most of it work but now the issue is the picker then selects the title on second click. What am i missing: Below is my code

```
public enum ResponseReason
{
    FirstReason = 1,
    SecondReason = 2,
    ThirdReason = 3
}
```

//inside ViewModel

```
public int ReasonValue { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ResponseReason> ShowResponseReason { 
  get
   {
     return new ObservableCollection<ResponseReason>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ResponseReason)).OfType<ResponseReason>().ToList());
   }
  }
```

//then picker

```
 <Picker
   ItemsSource="{Binding ShowResponseReason}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding ReasonValue}"
   Title="Please Select"
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}" />
```

Comment: You should use `SelectedIndex="{Binding ReasonValue}" ` to replece the `SelectedItem="{Binding ReasonValue}"`, because `ReasonValue` is `int` in your  viewmodel. But the index is start from 0 in `SelectedIndex` , not from 1, If it is not your issue, can you share a running GIF about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `SelectedItem`, `SelectedItem` must exist in the `ItemsSource`. Since you're returning a new `ItemsSource` object, the `SelectedItem` never exists in the newly return `ItemsSource`. You're `SelectedItem` type also needs to match your `ItemsSource` type. So `ReasonValue` should be type `ResponseReason`. Make these changes in your ViewModel:

```
public ResponseReason ReasonValue { get; set; }

private ObservableCollection<ResponseReason> mShowResponseReason = new ObservableCollection<ResponseReason>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ResponseReason)).OfType<ResponseReason>().ToList());
public ObservableCollection<ResponseReason> ShowResponseReason
{
    get => mShowResponseReason;
    set
    {
        mShowResponseReason = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now the `ItemsSource` will always contain the exact object that is `SelectedItem`.